# Can OrmLite handle queries that return multiple resultsets?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Using ServiceStack.OrmLite, If a query returns multiple resultsets how can I access all the resultsets and assingn each one to the respective POCO.
As example I have a single store procedure that have the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
GO
SELECT * FROM Products
```

I would like to assign 2 POCO objects(List.User and List.Product) with the result of the store procedure. And splitting the query in to 2 store procedures is not a option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it and also it is not a good practice.

In another cases you can load 1 table and its references. For example:

```
User
  int Id
  UserPermission Permissions

UserPermission
  int Id
  int UserId

-- this will load the references
var users = dbCon.LoadSelect<User>();
```